# RedGate SQL Compare 9 command line - STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE

Tags: redgate, schema-compare

I can't seem to find the switch to ignore STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE differences on PKs and INDEXES when scripting RedGate SQL Compare 9. Obviously something like /Options:ii will work but I want to compare the rest of the index.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in project options under Ignore->STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE property on indexes. If you don't see it you may need to upgrade.
From the command line the switch is /isn

Comment: Thanks but thats through the UI. I'm looking for the scripting option.

Comment: /isn has done the trick. Many thanks! I dont know if you want to add the answer to your response and I'll mark it as correct?